# Empty google worksheet before writing in it

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I use the [asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client%20%22asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) to read google spreadsheets and to write in google spreadsheets.

There are functions to update and delete the actual worksheet but not to empty the worksheet before i write data in it.
Knows somebody who use this library a way to empty the worksheet before writing in? If not you can not be sure that old data is still available

Comment: Delete > create > rename > write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal solution is delete the worksheet and recreate

```
// service
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();

// retrieve a list of worksheets from a spreadsheet 
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('Spreadsheet');
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed();

// get the worksheet you want to empty
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle('EmptySheet');

// delete the worksheet
$worksheet->delete();

// recreate the worksheet to be sure it's empty
$spreadsheet->addWorksheet('EmptySheet', rows, column);
```

**Edit**

Or use the batchUpdate with empty param `userEnteredValue`. Look at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#clear_a_sheet_of_all_values_while_preserving_formats

Comment: Sounds good. But what about the order of the worksheets in the spreadsheet, is that going to change then?

Comment: From the DOC https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets : "Important: It is currently not possible to set the order of worksheets in the UI via the Sheets API, outside of deleting and recreating all worksheets.".

Comment: @Loko look at batchUpdate https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#clear_a_sheet_of_all_values_while_preserving_formats

Comment: The batchUpdate options sound more usable for me. But how can i use this batchUpdate from the Google API when i use the asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client? I get the error code 403 with the message: "Google Sheets API has not been used in project spreadsheet-184712 before or it is disabled."

In my google console i use google drive api and not google spreadsheet api

Comment: Ok solved it, needed to get the `gid`and `spreadsheetId` with functions from the given library and used the code from the Link